# how to trigger event to window.matchMedia?

Tags: javascript

How to create and dispatch event to trigger `window.matchMedia('(orientation: portrait)')` callback, when I click on the button?

```
const mql = window.matchMedia('(orientation: portrait)');
mql.addListener(() => {
 console.log('GOT IT!');
});

document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', () => {

 window.dispatchEvent(???)
});
```